# Is it possible to create a folder with the filename into the tar file you are creating?

Tags: linux, tar

Let's say I'm trying to tar.gz all the files and folders in /usr/local/bin/data/*

The file name would be `data-2015-10-01.tar.gz`. When I untar it, is it possible that the root directory would be data-2015-10-01 followed by the contents of whatever is inside of data/* ?

If not, how can I tar /usr/local/bin/data/* but start at the /data/ folder level?

I can't do this unfortunately since the program spits out /usr/local/bin/data/ and I'm unable to change it.
     cd /usr/local/bin
     tar ... /data/*

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do what I think you're trying to accomplish. First, you can use the -C option to tar when creating the archive. That changes tar's current working directory to that directory before creating the archive. Not strictly required in your case, but probably helpful.

# tar -C /usr/local/bin -czf data-2015-10-01.tar.gz data/*

That at least gets you to a single directory named data. If you have control of the extraction (manually or via a script you provide to whomever is unpacking this), then you can do something like this on the extraction:

# mkdir -f data-2015-10-01 && tar -C data-2015-10-01 --strip-components=1 -xzf data-2015-10-01.tar.gz

This will remove the first path, which is "data" and extract everything from there into the directory which is your current working directory, data-2015-10-01. So, it isn't specifically tar that's doing the renaming, but you will effectively end up with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I've accomplished something similar with a symlink. This is not a great solution if you have (or might have) symlinks in the directory structure you're trying to archive. I have to say that I prefer @geis' solution to strip out the top-level directory on extract, but this gives you another option.

```
ln -s /usr/local/bin/data data-2015-10-01
tar -cvhf data-2015-10-01.tar.gz data-2015-10-01/
rm data-2015-10-01
```

(Note the additional `-h` option in the `tar` invocation.)